# ker$(A^n) =$ ker$(A^m), \forall m > n$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A$ is a square matrix and ker$(A^n) =$ ker$(A^{n+1})$, then
>   ker$(A^n) =$ ker$(A^m), \forall m > n$.

I'm trying to prove that this is correct, but I'm having trouble figuring out what the relation between the ker$(A^n)$ and ker$(A^{n+1})$ is precisely. I know "ker" represents all solutions to the homogenous equation, but I'm not sure how to think about something like ker$(A^n)$ where $A$ is raised to a power.

I can think of something like ker$(A_1\times ... \times A_n)$ = ker$(A_1\times ... \times A_{n+1})$, but is there some way I can transform this equation to make it easier to understand how to prove the above?

Comment: You are given that $A^{n}x=0 \iff A^{n+1}x=0$, and you want to show that $A^{n}x=0 \iff A^{m}x=0$ for any $m>n$.  (Notice that $A^{n}x=0\implies A^{m}x=A^{m-n}(A^{n}x)=A^{m-n}(0)=0$ if $m>n$.)

Comment: @user84413 How do we know that $A^nx = 0$ in the last line?

Comment: I'm showing that if $A^{n}x=0$, then $A^{m}x=0$ for $m>n$.

Comment: @user84413 How can you assume that $A^nx=0$ when considering ker$(A^m)$? Shouldn't we have some inductive steps here?

Comment: This shows that $ker(A^n)\subseteq ker(A^m)$ if $m>n$, so it is just the reverse inclusion that you must show by induction.

Comment: @user84413 can you possibly write an answer, I'm unsure what you mean here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of the problem in the following way:

> If we know that $A^{n+1}x = A^n \cdot Ax = 0 \implies A^n x = 0$ (for all $x$), show that
>   $A^m x = 0 \implies A^n x = 0$ for all $m>n$ (for all $x$).

In fact, it's enough to show the following:

> If we know that $A^{n+1}x = A^n \cdot Ax = 0 \implies A^n x = 0$ (for all $x$), show that
>   $A^m x = 0 \implies A^{m-1} x = 0$ for all $m>n$ (for all $x$).

Now, note that
$$
A^m x = A^{n+1}(A^{m-n-1} x) = 0
$$
and apply the hypothesis.

Comment: Would this be $A^{m-n-1}\cdot A \cdot A^nx = 0$ and since we know $A \cdot A^nx=0$ implies $A^nx=0$, we have that $A^{m-n-1}\cdot A \cdot 0 = 0$ which is just $0$?

Comment: See my edit; I mistyped earlier.  This should be much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ We want to prove that if $\ker(A^n)=\ker(A^{n+1})$, then $\ker(A^n)=\ker(A^{n+k})$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

We know this is true for $k=1$ by assumption, so assume that $\ker(A^n)=\ker(A^{n+k})$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

If $A^{n+k+1}(x)=0,$ then $A^{n+k}(Ax)=0\implies A^{n}(Ax)=0\implies A^{n+1}(x)=0\implies A^{n}(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We allways have that $\ker A^n\subseteq \ker A^{n+1}$ since multiplying by $A$ is just composing the transformation of $A^n$ with that of $A$ and $0$ always maps to $0$. So with induction you can prove $\ker A^n\subseteq\ker A^n$ if $m\geq n$

We shall now prove if $\ker A^{n+1}\subseteq\ker A^{n+1}$ then $\ker A^{n+2}\subseteq\ker A^{n+1}$. Suppose $A^{n+2}(v)=0$ then $A(v)\in \ker A^{n+1}=\ker A^n$ since $A(v)\in \ker A^n$ we have $A^{n+1}(v)=0$ so $A\in \ker A^{n+1}$.

As before induction proves $\ker A^m\subseteq \ker A^n$ if $m\geq n$