# Show that there is an $m\in\mathbb{N}_0$ So that $\ker(A)\subsetneq ...\subsetneq \ker(A^m)=\ker(A^{m+1})=...$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A:V\to V$ be an endomorphism of the finite dimensional vector space $V$. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ set $U_n := \ker(A^n)$ and $W_n := \text{Im}(A^n) $. Show that there is an $m\in \mathbb{N}_0$ so that:
\begin{equation}
W_1\supsetneq ...\supsetneq W_m=W_{m+1}=W_{m+2}=...
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
U_1\subsetneq ...\subsetneq U_m=U_{m+1}=U_{m+2}=...
\end{equation}

I don't know how could I start solving this. Could somebody give me a hand?

Comment: shouldn't the $W_i$ inclusion chain be reversed?

Comment: Pls have a look at
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953228/keran-keram-forall-m-n
Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $$v\in \ker(A^n)\Rightarrow A^nv=0\Rightarrow AA^nv=0\Rightarrow A^{n+1}v=0 \Rightarrow v\in\ker(A^{n+1})$$
and thus $U_n\subseteq U_{n+1}$. Similarly, if $w\in Im(A^n)$, then there exists $v\in V$ such that $A^nv=w$. Setting $Av=u$ gives us $A^{n-1}(Av) = A^{n-1}u = w$ which shows that $w\in Im(A^{n-1})$ and thus $W_{n+1}\subseteq W_n$. We have proved the subset inclusions.

To show these sequences of sets have a maximal element, you can observe that each of your spaces in the sequences $\{U_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{W_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are subspaces of the finite vector space $V$. Note that the dimensions of $U_n$ are increasing(non-decreasing) and the dimensions of $W_n$ are decreasing(non-increasing). Let $n$ be the dimension of your vector space $V$. If there is no $m$ such that $U_{m+i} = U_m$ for all positive integers $i$, then after finite steps, $U_M$ for some $M>m$ will equal the entire vector space $V$. I hope you can formulate this rigorously. Similar, argument holds for the sequence of $W_n$s (which will tend to the trivial vector space $\{0\}$ if it is not equal to some finite space $W_{M'}$.

Once it is established for $U_n$s you can apply the rank nullity theorem to get the result for $W_n$s.

(If you vector space is nilpotent, then $U_M = V$ and $W_{M'}=\{0\}$.)

Comment: Thanks! One more question... Why is the dimension of $\{U_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ increasing? (I suppose the dimension is given by n, but why?)

Comment: Hint: Since V is finite-dimensional, there can only be finite strictly ascending or descending chains of vector subspaces of V since the dimension has to be strictly increasing or decreasing in such a chain, respectively. So all you have to do is to show that $\ker (A^{k})$ forms an ascending chain and $Im(A^{k})$ a descending chain.

Comment: If $U_n = U_{n+1}$, then both the subspaces can be spanned by the a single basis. If $U_n \subset U_{n+1}$, then there exists atleast one vector in $U_{n+1}$ which does not belong to $U_n$. The union of this vector (and other appropriate vectors if necessary) and the basis of $U_n$ gives you a basis of $U_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks! your answers were really helpful.